# Function to set tableColumn.setOnEditCommit passing item value to set as function parameter

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tableview

I would like to be able to set up javaFX TableView columns with the minimum of repetitive code. The following example does that except for the problem with setOnEditCommit.
Any help much appreciated.

```
lateinit var tblDirs: TableView<SrcItem>
lateinit var tcSrcItem: TableColumn<SrcItem, String>
lateinit var tcDestItem: TableColumn<SrcItem, String>

data class SrcItem {
    var src: String = ""
    var dest: String = ""
    var destProperty
        get() = SimpleStringProperty(dest)
        set(value) {src = value.toString()}
    var srcProperty
        get() = SimpleStringProperty(src)
        set(value) {src = value.toString()}
}

private fun initTblDirs() {
    tblDirs.isEditable = true
    tcSrcItem = setupColumn(0, "src")
    tcDestItem = setupColumn(1, "dest")
}

fun setupColumn(col: Int, valName: String): TableColumn<SrcItem, String> {
    val tc = tblDirs.columns[col]  as TableColumn<SrcItem, String>
    tc.cellValueFactory = PropertyValueFactory<SrcItem, String>(valName)
    tc.cellFactory = TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn();
    tc.setOnEditCommit { it.tableView.items[it.tablePosition.row].valName??? = it.newValue }
    tc.isEditable = true
    return tc
}
```

I cannot figure a way of passing the column value parameter in setupColumn() to setOnEditCommit in setupColumn()
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Pass a function that accepts the edited item as well as the new value and sets the appropriate property: `(SrcItem, String) -> Unit`. You'd then call this function in the `onEditCommit` handler with the appropriate values.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Though I still wonder if it can be done by passing just 2 function parameters - the column number and the column data name.

Comment: Might be possible with reflection.

Comment: Yes, I might look into that one day, but at present I am ignorant when it comes to reflection.